# Unable to find template AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello.html.twig Symfony 2 while debugging using PHPed

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phped

I have installed Symfony 2 onto a virtual Linux server. I use Windows and PHPED to work and debug my Symfony 2 project. I have not configured anything on symfony 2, I debug the hello world example via using PHPEDs debug browser plugin.

Everything works fine apart from when it hits Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 202 and cant find the following file "AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello.html.twig" in Resources/views folder. There is a file hello.html.twig which I think is the file it is trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

The file should be at this location

```
src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Demo/hello.html.twig
```

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#templates